# Does everyone wear boots in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, clothing

I noticed that almost everyone appears to wear boots in the Star Wars films and cartoons, from Jedi to Sith, farmer to worker, child to old. The only ones that don't seem to be those who [go barefoot](https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-1la5hnl_2fa0d1d4.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1200%2C674) or have [no feet](https://youtu.be/zJSOzztOhKc?t=29).

Boots are clearly *very* popular in the Galaxy far, far away, but excluding the footless and footloose, are there any cases where someone is wearing *other kinds of shoes* in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: Look at Mos Eisley.  Gravel, barely improved roads (no wheeled vehicles, so no need to pave) so "sneakers" would seem to be less practical than boots.  Rebels spend their time running around in jungles, caverns...

Comment: @DavidW  But the dignitaries in Coruscant also prefer boots when walking on the shiny marble pavements.

Comment: "It's just that  ̶m̶a̶s̶k̶s̶  boots are terribly comfortable – I think everyone will be wearing them in the future,”

Comment: This is a case of tail-wag-dog. Luke wears shoes with ankle wraps because he lives in the desert, as does Obi-Wan. Han wears leather boots because he's a space cowboy and everyone else in the series wears them because Luke, Obi-Wan and Han wore them

Comment: Although they aren't visible a lot, in his first appearance Lando has some [nice shoes](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/f/f1/Wookvs.lando.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070411174318), as you would expect.

Comment: Looking through my copies of *Star Wars Costumes - The Original Trilogy* and *Dressing a Galaxy: The Costumes of Star Wars*, it strikes me that everyone's wearing boots ;-)

Comment: @Cadence - https://i0.wp.com/bamfstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/lando-cl2-boots.jpg?ssl=1 they look like boots to me

Comment: I've taken the liberty of tidying up your question a little. I understood what you meant, but there was some scope for confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Attack of the Clones

Padmé wears white pumps in the fields of Naboo.

[image]

Padmé wears silver pumps by the lake on Naboo.

[image]

Although they aren't really seen on screen, Padmé wears [these sensible leather shoes](https://www.thekesselrunway.com/museum-replicas-padme-shoes/) under her 'packing gown' when getting ready to leave Corsucant.

[image]

### A New Hope

Leia wears silver shoes at the 'Medal Ceremony'.

[image]

### The Empire Strikes Back

Leia wears shiny burgundy slip-ons while at Bespin.

[image]

### Return of the Jedi

Admiral Ackbar wears white brogues (described in the [*Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary) as "*positive grip shoes*") and his assistants are clearly wearing  pairs of white lace-up sneakers aboard the *Home One*.

[image]

Bib Fortuna wears these "soft soled shoes" when sneaking around Jabba's Palace.

[image]

### Solo

Qi'ra wears a nice pair of strappy shoes when meeting Han and Beckett.

[image]

And Dryden Vos is wearing what appears to be a pair of white-soled sneakers when fighting Han.

[image]

Comment: Snoke wore [gold slippers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Snoke%27s_slippers?file=Snoke_Slippers_DK.jpg) but you don't really see them in the film

Comment: The ewoks wear leaf shoes; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leaf_shoe?file=Kneesaa_leaf_shoes.jpg

Comment: Valorum - that feels almost like a leg-pull: "Snoke was originally going to talk about his slippers in the movie, but the piece of dialogue was removed from the final cut." - were they going for a "Pulp Fiction" vibe with some inconsequential chatter about the everyday tribulations of being an Evil Overlord? (wildly presuming from your other answers that you've read the referenced "The Art of Star Wars: The Last Jedi")

Comment: @TomGoodfellow - I think the implication was that there was a single line in which they're mentioned rather than an extended sequence where he discusses them with Ren and Hux

Answer (score -1):

As homage to steampunk and buck rogers era scifi. Boots are predominant footwear. In the comics sandals, heels, barefooted characters bound.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for lack of context. First image doesn't have her wearing shoes at all, second image isn't from a comic, it's from Star Wars: Forces of Destiny

Comment: @Valorum I think that although she isn't wearing shoes in the first image, they are on the ground to the right of the image.